# Calling a class-based-view from template

Tags: django-templates, django-urls

I'm new to Django/Python  and working with Django 2. 
In urls.py I defined:

```
> urlpatterns = [    path('delivery/add'/,views.DeliveryCreate.as_view(),name='delivery-add'), ]
```

Within the template (app/template/app/main.html) the call is:

```
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Deliveries
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">           
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'delivery/add'  %}">Create Delivery ...</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

The template (app/template/app/delivery_form.html) exists

but this results in an Exception value

```
Reverse for 'delivery/add' not found. 'delivery/add' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

With `path('delivery-add'/...)` instead of `path('delivery/add'/...)` it works for  `href="{% url 'delivery-add'...%}`

Why it doesn't work with  '/add' ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The `{% url %}` template tag and `reverse` function both work with the `name` of your url pattern, not the actual url!

So since you've defined your pattern as

```
urlpatterns = [ path('delivery/add'/, views.DeliveryCreate.as_view(),name='delivery-add'), ]
```

i.e with a name of `'delivery-add'` then you have to pass that to `{% url %}` as you've already experienced, i.e `{% url 'delivery-add' %}` will work.

Also please notice that there's a trailing `/` *outside* of the string in your pattern ( `path('delivery/add'/...` ) that `/` definitely needs to be removed!